# How to play movie file on a curved plane?

Tags: uv, node-editor, video

I need help with how to get a movie file to play on a curved plane. I know how to uv map an image on a curved plane "see blue curved plane in 3D set below". But can’t seem to figure out how to map a movie file to it. I thought about adding image as planes and adding a movie file that way, but then I don’t know how to curve that plane without subdividing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My guess is I’m probably thinking about it all wrong.

[image: Set with video wall]

Comment: have you tried first making the plane a curve and then playing the movie clip?

Comment: why don't you want to subdivide the plane? Also, as Aster17 says, you could first create your bent plane and give it an Image Texture with the movie uploaded but it would be the same

Comment: Thanks for the input. Got me realizing I was think about this a bit wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a plane
2. press tab to enter edit mode
3. right mouse click -> subdivide plane -> 10
4. s -> x -> size your plane as much as you like
5. tab to go to object mode
6. add simple deform modifier
7. choose bend -> z axis and whatever angle you like

[image]

8. go to shader editor and build these nodes:

[image]

9. hit space and enjoy the animation

you can also wait a little while because my internet upload speed is slow as hell and then watch my tutorial about it:

https://youtu.be/v5gbEg3Qwz8

Comment: Thanks Chris for the speedy and straight forward solution!

Comment: you are welcome